# How do I limit checklist options based on role?

Tags: laravel-backpack

I have a roles field.

```
if (!is('admin')) {
            $this->crud->removeField('roles_permissions');
        }
```

I want a user with the admin role to have access to all options in this checklist field. However, a user with a client role should have access to these roles but only specific ones.

I tried this:

```
if (is('client')) {
                $this->crud->addField([
                    'label' => ucFirst(__('Roles')),
                    'name' => 'roles',
                    'type' => 'checklist',
                    'model' => 'Backpack\PermissionManager\app\Models\Role',
                    'attribute' => 'name',
                ]);
            }
```

But how do I limit the options coming from the model?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to pass all options to the `checklist` field by using the `options` attribute:

```php
$this->crud->addField([
    'label' => ucFirst(__('Roles')),
    'name' => 'roles',
    'type' => 'checklist',
    'model' => 'Backpack\PermissionManager\app\Models\Role',
    'attribute' => 'name',
    'options' => [
        1 => 'smth',
        2 => 'smth else',
    ] 
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Passing array is not working for me. I think it needs a callback.

```php
$this->crud->addField([
    'label' => ucFirst(__('Roles')),
    'name' => 'roles',
    'type' => 'checklist',
    'model' => 'Backpack\PermissionManager\app\Models\Role',
    'attribute' => 'name',
    'options' => (function ($query) {
       return $query->where('id', '<>', 1)->orderBy('id')->pluck('name', 'id');
    }),
]);
```